# find orders for three consecutive weeks

Tags: sql-server

I have table like the below which has overlapping weeks from two years 2018 and 2019. I want to identify the first set of 3 consecutive weeks for each customer using TSQL.

[image: Order details]

The resultset should have the customer_id and the max(order_date) from the first set of 3 consecutive weeks like below.

[image: Resultset]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting images of data isn't well received, data is textual and so should be posted as `text`; or even better as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements. The volunteers you're asking help from also expect you to do a little bit of due diligence. Instead of requesting us to do the work for you, show us what you have tried, explain why it didn't work and ask a about that. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, so please don't treat it as one. Thanks.

Comment: sorry about that, will make sure i do it properly the next time

Comment: Why next time? You're far more likely to get an answer if you follow the [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) advice.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own data. Try running this (this uses windowing functions which is a 2012 and on feature):

```
 create table i1(i1 int identity (1,1) primary key, idate date, name varchar(25));
 insert into i1 values ('1-1-2019','b'),  ('1-8-2019','b'), ('1-15-2019','b'),
 ('1-1-2019','c'),  ('1-8-2019','c'), ('1-24-2019','c'),('1-31-2019','c')

 ;
 with ct1 as (select name,idate, datepart(ww,idate) -lag(datepart(ww,idate),1,0)  over (partition by name order by idate) diff
    ,row_number() over (partition by name order by idate) id from i1),
          ct2 as (
   select name ,  idate,sum(diff) over ( partition by name order by idate rows between  3 preceding and current row) diff2 
     from ct1)



select   name, idate
   from ct2 where diff2=3
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin,
It doesnt work when there are weeks from overlapping years(2018 and 2019). For example if you insert another record into i1 ('12-25-2018','b'), I expect the query to return '2019-01-08' but instead it is returning 2019-01-15

create table i1(i1 int identity (1,1) primary key, idate date, name varchar(25));
 insert into i1 values **('12-25-2018','b')**,('1-1-2019','b'),  ('1-8-2019','b'), ('1-15-2019','b'),
 ('1-1-2019','c'),  ('1-8-2019','c'), ('1-24-2019','c'),('1-31-2019','c')